# How main function call in C++

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

I have created function and call above the main() function. It is successfully call the function in GCC compiler on Linux platform. I don't understand, how main function call my own function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myFunc();

int ret = myFunc();

int main()
{
    cout << ret << endl;
}

int myFunc()
{
    int i = 10, j = 20, k;
    k = i+j;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: "I don't understand, how main function call my own function. " - it doesn't - it's called before main and you print out the return value.

Comment: Silly stuff and complete misunderstanding needs to read [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Global variables are initialized *before* `main` is called. Therefore the call to `myFunc` happens before `main` is called. Your `main` function doesn't call `myFunc` at all.

It would have been very obvious if you used a debugger and set breakpoints in the `myFunc` and `main` functions, and looking at the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

As Some programmer dude explained, it is being called before the `main` function.

To not be confused, I suggest that you explicitly call the `myFunc()` in the `main` function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myFunc();

int main()
{
    int ret = myFunc();
    cout << ret << endl;
}

int myFunc()
{
    int i = 10;
    int j = 20;
    return i+j;
}
```